# Android: how to make keyboard enter button say "Search" and handle its click?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I can't figure this out. Some apps have an EditText (textbox) with the help of which, when you touch it and it brings up the on-screen keyboard, the keyboard has a "Search" button instead of an enter key.

I want to implement this. How can I implement that Search button and detect the press of the Search button?

**Edit**: found how to implement the Search button; in XML, `android:imeOptions="actionSearch"` or in Java, `EditTextSample.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH);`. But how do I handle the user pressing that Search button? Does it have something to do with `android:imeActionId`?

Comment: Note that imeOptions might not work on some devices. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470018/alternative-of-action-done-button-in-htc-desire) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886677/imeoptions-on-htc-devices).

Answer (score 1027, accepted):

In the layout set your input method options to search.

```
<EditText
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch" 
    android:inputType="text" />
```

In the java add the editor action listener.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            performSearch();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

In kotlin use below:

```
 editText.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
          performSearch()
        }
        true
      }
```

Comment: what if we want to get the keys on which the user clicks, like a,b,c?

Comment: On os 2.3.6 it doesn't work until I put android:inputType="text" attribute.

Comment: Shouldn't both of those TextView's say EditText instead?

Comment: android:inputType="text" was also required for me on Android 2.3.5 and 4.0.4

Comment: I found if the keyboard is in Swype mode, search button doesn't appear, at least for Galaxy SII (2.3.4)

Comment: I think you need to add a listener as well to the text edit otherwise the keyboard does not appear properly just by the `actionSearch` IME option in the layout file.

Comment: @Carol `EditText` is a sub class of `TextView`.

Comment: Probably better is even android:inputType="textFilter". (Which seems to work for me on 2.3.7)

Comment: android:inputType="text" is also required for 4.4.0 - 4.4.2 (Android Kitkat).

Comment: Yup, android:inputType="text" is still needed in 5.0 :)

Comment: I also had to add `android:singleLine="true"` for the search icon to appear.

Comment: Have not tried with inputtype text, but it works fine with inputtype numberdecimal

Comment: android:inputType="text" was also required for me on 7.0 (Android Nougat)

Comment: Yes, android:inputType="text" is still required

Answer (score 29):

Hide keyboard when user clicks search. Addition to Robby Pond answer

```
private void performSearch() {
    editText.clearFocus();
    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    //...perform search
}
```

Answer (score 15):

In `xml` file, put `imeOptions="actionSearch"` and `inputType="text"`, `maxLines="1"`:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/search"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1" />
```

Answer (score 12):

In Kotlin

```
evLoginPassword.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        doTheLoginWork()
    }
    true
}
```

Partial Xml Code

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
       <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/evLoginUserEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@color/black_54_percent" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/evLoginPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:textColor="@color/black_54_percent" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for TextInputEditText :

In the layout XML file set your input method options to your required type. for example **done**.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionGo"/>
```

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

Similarly, you can also set imeOptions to actionSubmit, actionSearch, etc

In the java add the editor action listener.

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);

textInputLayout.getEditText().setOnEditorActionListener(new 

    TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
                performYourAction();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

If you're using kotlin :

```
textInputLayout.editText.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
        performYourAction()
    }
    true
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful for Android/Kotlin newbies to know where this snippet should go, and within what context it should be ...

Comment: If you are a total newbie I would suggest putting these code snippets into your onCreate method or onCreateView method of your activity or fragment.

Comment: thank you. I found the answer and put in in onCreate() in activity. The other part of my question had to do with context, as "testInputLayout" was unclear. my solution was:
findViewById( R.id.search_request_layout ).editText?.setOnEditorActionListener { _, actionId, _ -> // do something }

Answer (score 0):

by XML:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:inputType="text" />
```

By Java:

```
 editText.clearFocus();
    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```