# Alternative of Action done button in HTC desire?

Tags: android

I wrote code for one application.In that I wrote IME_ACTION_DONE for edit text.All other devices support for this action but in HTC desire I haven't get this 'done' softkeyboard button.How can i get this soft button in HTC desire other wise please give me alternative for this done button functionality on EditText without lot of changes in my application to use with HTC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is not just with HTC. No IME implementation is obligated to support the action button. I am sure there are any number of soft keyboards, therefore, that will have the same effect.

> please give me alternative for this done button functionality on EditText without lot of changes in my application to use with HTC.

Use a `Button` widget in the activity. Or, use an options menu choice. You needed that anyway, as hardware keyboards lack an action button, and so you need some UI for them as well.

Answer (score 1):

To account for other keyboards not listening! You could also do this.

```
yourEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    // Hides the keyboard on HTC devices that do not comply with imeOptions="actionDone"
    // You could wrap this in a device check if you just want to single out HTC
    ((InputMethodManager) v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: My `Motorola DROID RAZR HD` is not hiding the Number KeyPad when done button is pressed. Does this code works for all the devices ? If yes, then why only to wrap for `HTC` ?