# Issue in handling Key ENTER event in search interface of an android fragment

Tags: android, search, interface

I am using search interface in one of my fragments. I want to handle **"Enter KeyEvent"** in the edittext of the search interface.Whenever the user presses enter in the edittext of the search I want to do something that time. I can make use of onTextSubmit() method but its not detecting the enter key press event when the edittext is empty.

But I want to handle the enter key event when the edit text is empty.Can someone help me ?

Comment: are you using actionbar sherlock...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check by this:

```
yourEditView.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                // Perform action on Enter key press
                if(yourEditView.isEmpty()&&yourEditView.lengh()==0){
                  // Perform your task here
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i have used both of them ,

First is for [Enter Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext) to do some task while click on Enter.

```
  <EditText android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"/> 

    editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
    {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            {
                switch (keyCode)
                {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        addCourseFromTextBox();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Second is for [Search key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205339/android-how-to-make-keyboard-enter-button-say-search-and-handle-its-click) to search some text.

```
<EditText android:imeOptions="actionSearch" 
    android:inputType="text"/> 

editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
            performSearch();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Check out [all imeOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html)  in detail.

Comment: How do you get the edit text from the search interface?                     <item android:id="@+id/search"
          android:title="@string/search_title"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
          android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />                                      I am using this in my menu.xml file to have the search interface in my fragment

Comment: I don't understand how do you get edit text like this when using an search interface. Can u explain me bit clearly?  I referred this link"http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html" to implement my search interface. I am a newbie to android. Please help me